# Работа с .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

У меня есть файл site.xyz/category.php
К нему идет GET запрос site.xyz/category.php?category=funny
Мне нужно сделать чтобы при обращении site.xyz/category/funny/ перенаправляло на site.xyz/category.php?category=funny

Comment: `RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/$ $1.php?$1=$2 [L]` как-то так. Но лучше конечно единую точку входа делать для ЧПУ и роутинг средствами php

Comment: не работает ваш код(

Answer (score 0):

Положите в кореневую папку сайта файл `.htaccess` следующего содержания:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/category/([^/]+)/$
RewriteRule .* /category.php?category=%1 [QSA,L]
```

**UPD** теперь название категории определяется через паттерн

Comment: мне будет не удобно добавляя новую категорию видео и потом это прописывать в htaccess

Comment: Я вам показал решение, основываясь на условиях вашего вопроса. Я обновил свой ответ.